# How to use BeautifulSoup 4 to search for a specific word

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, lxml

i recently installed beautifulsoup4 and lxml because i thought they would work to the project i am working on. I have been working on this for 2 days now and still got no solution for my main function.

what i am trying to do is simple:
1. check if player is in the list
2. if player is in list return "Found" if not return "Not found"

But i am unable to make this work.

edit: changed the function a little

```
def FindPlayer(input):
    ## I am trying to look for player in Server Status
    Page = urlopen("http://www.rockmc.com/").read()
    raw = bs4.BeautifulSoup(Page, "lxml")
    HTML = raw.get_text()
    test = raw.find_all(input)
    print(test) ## Debugging
Findplayer("PlayerGuy")
```

Comment: what list on that website would you check for a player? The "online users" or "server status"? currently "online users" shows "none", and "server status" lists 2 users. Which would you want to check?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve], instead of just this one function.

Comment: @downshift i am trying to look for players in server status when there are some there

Comment: @JohnDoe, that website appears to load everything through scripts(Javascript), and since Beautifulsoup can't execute javascript code, you'll probably need to use something like Selenium or PhantomJS

Comment: @downshift Thanks, i didnt hit me that the site is only in javascript

Comment: @JohnDoe, I didn't realize it also, until I tried to scrape the page and only got back one line of javascript. You can see it if you clear your browser cache for that page, then turn off Javascript in your browser and reload the page, it's blank. It's still very possible to do it, we're just going to have to use different tools.

Comment: @downshift how can i put your comment as answer for this question?

Comment: Sure you can, just write an answer in the Answer box at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Selenium to do search for what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

As `get_text()` returns `string` you can search for `input` to check if it's a substring of `HTML`. Try this:

```
def FindPlayer(input):
    ## I am trying to look for player in Server Status
    Page = urlopen("http://www.rockmc.com/").read()
    raw = bs4.BeautifulSoup(Page, "lxml")
    HTML = raw.get_text()
    test = ""
    if(HTML.find(input) > -1):
        test = input
    print(test) ## Debugging
Findplayer("PlayerGuy")
```

Comment: I tried this, i do not get any error but it dont work neither